# Android From gridview layout index convert into row and column

Tags: android, gridview, matrix, grid

If I have index starting from 0, of a position on a grid, how can I turn that into a row, column? I'm getting incorrect results with the following. Fortunately I know how many rows and columns I have and in my case its 11 by 11.

```
int column = position % columns;

int row = position / columns;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// x : horizontal position in range [0; columns-1]
// y : vertical position in range [0; rows-1]

int x = index % columns;
int y = index / columns;
int column = x + 1;
int row = y + 1;
```

to reverse:

```
int index = x + y * columns;
```

or

```
int index = (column - 1) + (row - 1) * columns;
```

Comment: Do I understand your question?

Comment: Thanks. This is correct. x = column and y is row.  I do start from one though on this. I test it out and I was one less so I just added one to end of result of both x and y. That seem to work.

Comment: If I can advise you, forget immediately the counts which starts at '1' as column & row. It is a big source of problems, always use dimensions starting at 0

Comment: @alex how to save value as a matrix in gridview like i i want to increase num of columns and rows then value not changing its position just increase gridview size android