# Android Java shortest path from two indexes on gridview

Tags: android, gridview, matrix, shortest-path

If I have two points gather from onClick and they come as indexes or positions on the grid, how can I calculate weather to go up, down, left and right, diagonals are not allowed for the shortest route to the other point? So if i have pointA and pointB and point B is trying to get to pointA in the shortest path and I would recalculate this after every movement because pointA will move after movment from point B. What I have started to write is to find the adjacent positions around pointB without diagonals so points that are on edge will have less options obviously but how do I determine right movement with choices of neighboring squares? Should pointB go up,down,left and down preferably using indexes?  I'm indexing from zero and its 11 by 11 grid so 11 columns. Something I just thought of is deal with choices that have the same distance, to select at random between them.

```
0  1   2  3  4 ...
11 12 13 14 15 ...
22 23 24 25 16 ...
33 34 35 36 37 ...
etc...
```

I find array of indexes that I now can try to pick for the shortest path

```
Integer[] getAdjacentPositions(int position) 
{ 
   /*This will return integer array of positions that adjacent to position that is
    pass through that are not diagonal.*/ 

    Integer[] columnRow = new Integer[8];
    int columns = 11;
    int column = (position % columns);
    int row = (position / columns);
    int numberedges = 0;

    Log.d(TAG, "position inside of isedgeitem is " + position );
    Log.d(TAG, "row is " + row );
    Log.d(TAG, "column is " + column );

    for (int rowOffset = -1; rowOffset <= 1; rowOffset++) 
    {
        final int actRow = row + rowOffset;

        for (int columnOffset = -1; columnOffset <= 1; columnOffset++) 
        {
            final int actColumn = column + columnOffset;

            if (actRow >= 0 && actRow < 11 && actColumn >= 0 && actColumn < 11) 
                {
                    if (!isOneOfDiagonals(position, (actColumn + actRow * columns)))
                        {
                            columnRow[numberedges]= actColumn + actRow * columns; 
                            numberedges++;
                        }
                    Log.d(TAG, " actColumn" + actColumn );
                    Log.d(TAG, " actRow" + actRow );

                }

        }
    }

    return columnRow;


}
```

Now what to do with this array of Int Indexes to find the shortest path

```
shortestnextposition(Integer[] positions, int pointA )
    {

    return int position;


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly the problem:

- Difference between X positions of A and B : dX = Math.abs(ax - bx)
- Difference between Y positions of A and B : dY = Math.abs(ay - by)
- The shortest distance is : dX + dY

The problem with the shortest path is you can have different ways which uses the number of moves shortest distance. But you can code a preference in this move, for example, if you have to go from 0 to 24, the shortest distance is 3 and you have 3 shortest possible ways:

- [0,11,22,23]
- [0,1,12,23]
- [0,11,12,23]

I suppose you want to use the third possibility?

For that, compare dX and dY and move in the greater dimension, if dX > dY, move X, if dY > dX, moveY

---

**Update :** try this

```
public static int[] shortestPath(int x, int a, int b) {
    int ax = a % x, ay = a / x, bx = b % x, by = b / x;
    int[] path = new int[Math.abs(ax - bx) + Math.abs(ay - by) + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < path.length; i++)
        path[i] = a = i == 0 ? a : getAdjacentInDirectionOf(x, a, b);
    return path;
}

public static int getAdjacentInDirectionOf(int x, int a, int b) {
    int ax = a % x, ay = a / x, bx = b % x, by = b / x;
    int dx = Math.abs(ax - bx), dy = Math.abs(ay - by);
    if (dx >= dy) return (int) (ax + Math.signum(bx - ax) + ay * x);
    else return (int) (ax + (ay + Math.signum(by - ay)) * x);
}
```

---

**Update :** replace shortestPath() method from previous by this one to avoid first case

```
public static int[] shortestPath(int x, int a, int b) {
    int ax = a % x, ay = a / x, bx = b % x, by = b / x;
    int[] path = new int[Math.abs(ax - bx) + Math.abs(ay - by)];
    for (int i = 0; i < path.length; i++)
        path[i] = a = getAdjacentInDirectionOf(x, a, b);
    return path;
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about recalculating after each move so I'm not nesscary worry about return all of the path but I htink i have to find all of the path to determine which way to go. The reason I have to recalculate is the pointA will move after pointB moves where I'm calculating from for the shortest path. So after moving either 11 or 1, I would recalculate. SO i have to choose between only 1 to 4 choices in every case and if there are  more then 1 that are equal then I would choose at random to simplified it

Comment: How would I add an addition condition in determine path.  If the adjacent square is of a particular quality (certain color) it should remove it self from being in the path.  Not sure where I can make this evaluation? I would want to remove that index from being in set of possible indexes in path. It would be possible that all adjacent surrounding indexes could be eliminated and there would be no where to go. Where could I insert if condition in the iteration? "If adjacent square == blue then remove from possible shortest path and recalculate without adjacent square"

Comment: To make it easier I be concern with the first move on the path because I can just recalculate after the move.

Comment: Can explain the second update? So ternary operator is remove. What is the thinking here?

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what you want. The second update is for avoid the first move element in the array, isn't what you wanted? This functions helped you?

Comment: I think I confused because I needed to put a evaluation if statement to get rid of any paths with yellow in them.  I want only avoid the first element if it is yellow? If is is yellow then recalculate a new path without the yellow circle.  See picture above.

Comment: What is difference between the two shortestPath() functions?

Comment: The first one return an array with the point A included at first position, the second one return an array without the point A

Comment: I was just trying to understand your formula in getAdjacentInDirectionOf.  The last two lines in particular.  "if (dx >= dy) return (int) (ax + Math.signum(bx - ax) + ay * x);
    else return (int) (ax + (ay + Math.signum(by - ay)) * x);"  Is this a math formula? How did you come to this?  What does it mean? Or what is it doing? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Also I made another posting with similar question but with only available nodes?!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536295/android-java-gridview-find-shortest-path-from-available-nodes-indexes

Comment: I explain it just before update, dX and dY are difference between points A and B in X axis and Y axis. If the difference in X axis is superior or equals to the difference in Y axis, so move in X axis in priority. In the return statement, I use a previous formula I gave you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22494565/android-from-gridview-layout-index-convert-into-row-and-column/22495344#22495344 to find the index of the new element.